# Passing pytest fixtures to non-pytest code

Tags: python, pytest

When `f.result` is called normally, it returns `1`.  However when I test `f`, I want to pass the return value of fixture `my_var` to `f` so the `assert` in `test_stuff` returns `True`.

Is there a pytest feature that will facilitate this?

```
# conftest.py
import pytest
@pytest.fixture()
def my_var():
  b = 2
  return b
```

```
# test_stuff.py
import pytest
from mycode import f

def test_stuff():
  assert f.result == 2


"""
./tests/test_stuff.py::test_stuff Failed: [undefined]assert 1 == 2
 +  where 1 = f.result
def test_stuff():
>     assert f.result == 2
E     assert 1 == 2
E      +  where 1 = f.result

tests/test_stuff.py:5: AssertionError
"""
```

```
# mycode.py
class f:
  
  ## Pytest fixture to cast b as my_var here?
  def thing(a: int, b: int = None) -> int:
    ## Or maybe a way to cast b as my_var here?
    if not b:
      return a
    else:
      return b

  result = thing(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(f.result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work when you pass the fixture to test function and call f with the argument, something like this:

```
def test_stuff(my_var):
  f1 = f(my_var)
  assert f1.result == my_var
```